# how to make a div stays in place while scrolled without jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, css

how to make a div stays in place while scrolled without jquery?

I wanted to make something like the The New Stuff |  The Next Big Thing |  What's Hot

header part of mashable without using jquery (only javascript)

can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this HTML:

```
<div id="myElement" style="position: absolute">This stays at the top</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $('#myElement').css('top', $(this).scrollTop() + "px");
});
```

It attaches an event to the window's scroll and moves the element down as far as you've scrolled.

Comment: OP asked to do it without jquery.

Answer (score 4):

Did you try CSS `position:fixed` with top and left set? It is the only way to make it happen without scripting.

Comment: this won't work because the div i'm working on isn't at the top.

Comment: It's just a simple code with divs.... please check mashable.com and look at <div class="headers"> changes to <div class="headers fixed "> when scrolled.

Comment: so there also they have used `position : fixed !important;` in `.fixable-wrapper .fixed` class with `top:44px` defined.

Answer (score 2):

You can very well do that using css.

```
#id_name{position:fixed;top:some_value;left:some_value;}
```

this will fix the div at the corresponding value you have given for left and top position

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS Fixed position :

```
position:fixed;
```

And then position the element in relation to the window

```
left:50px;
top:50px;
```

This will fix the element in the window 50px from the top left corner.

You can manipulate this in Javascript in the onscroll event if you only want it to occur if they scroll to a certain height.

Comment: can you give me the code for that in javascript? just not using jquery? :( @Nunners

Comment: I'm not very sure how to do this in Javascript alone but I'd assume it is a fairly long winded approach. jQuery on the other hand is a very small approach for this. May I ask why you are so opposed to using jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

use css to place a div as fixed so that it will not scroll:

```
position:fixed
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the below demo. Hope this help

[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/t8PYZ/1/)

```
<div class = "hello">
    <ul>
        <li>Welcome </li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: hi thanks for your help but the div i want to position fix is in the middle of the page? :(

Comment: Can you please share the html or a js fiddle demo

Comment: Hi @piyush do you think this can be done with javascript using the offsetTop function??

Comment: offsetTop will give you the vertical offset position of an element. when you scroll up or down it will vary. Css I think is much better way to make it as fix in middle of the page. Use position fixed or absolute (depends) on your DOM structure